# What is expected if one wants to visit a research lab as a fresh PhD graduate?

Tags: research-process, visiting

I'm planning on visiting a lab during my trip to another country. I'm just getting my PhD, so I'm not a student anymore, and maybe not experienced enough to be a visiting lecture. Visiting students, visiting lecturers or post docs might be welcomed, but I'm not sure for my case.

Is it okay to e-mail to possible labs if people like me can visit the lab(s) for about a month? What is expected in return? Do we have to give a talk, or produce some result? Or is it okay to just learn from them, without directly contributing anything?

Comment: A month is a very short period. Depending on your motivation, you might want to visit for longer, e.g., 3-6 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay to e-mail...labs[, after getting a PhD, to ask] if people [I] can visit the lab(s) for about a month?

Yes. Your email should explain what you want and what you'll provide in return.

> What is expected in return? Do [I] have to give a talk, or produce some result?

A contribution should be expected from both sides. That contribution might be in the form of research that both sides conduct together, either side learning something from talks or by teaching, and you might be paid.

> Or is it okay to just learn from them, without directly contributing anything?

No. Any visit has to be mutually beneficial.